# How are currency units used with Python Pint units?

Tags: python, currency, units-of-measurement, pint

I would like to do something like this:

```
import pint
ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()

kg = ureg.kg
USD = ureg.USD  # not the way to do this

weight = 2.3 * kg
price = 1.49 * USD / kg
cost = weight * price
print(f"{cost:~.2f}")

>>> 3.43 USD
```

The Pint docs including the tutorial are not very clear on this.

The error I get with this code is:

pint.errors.UndefinedUnitError: 'USD' is not defined in the unit registry

So, how do I define USD in the unit registry?

Comment: You said the Pint docs aren't very clear on how to define a unit -- did you read the section on "defining units"?  https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/defining.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ureg.define()`](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/defining.html#programmatically) to define a new unit.  There is no "currency" dimension in the default registry, but you can just add one at the same time you define your unit.

```
import pint
ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()

ureg.define('USD = currency')

kg = ureg.kg
USD = ureg.USD

weight = 2.3 * kg
price = 1.49 * USD / kg
cost = weight * price
print(f"{cost:~.2f}")  # prints '3.43 USD'
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks very much. I read the docs several times but just didn't get it.

Comment: I'm new to `pint`, but it looks like you can do `ureg.define('USD = [currency]')` to define `currency` as a new base dimension that will work in things like `5 * ureg('USD / kWh')`.